# R help on Vector access

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I am new to R and trying to understand the effect of the following code.

```
    > x <- c(1, 2)
    > x[0]
    numeric(0)
    > x[FALSE]
    numeric(0
    > x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
    [1] 2
```

Specifically, having extensive background in C and C++, I am interesting in knowing what R does internally when accessing an element at index 0. I know that R has 1 based array indexing. But in this specific case, does it access the vector and then remove the result (numeric(0)) or does it remove 0 from the vector and show the results?

So, I want to know what is the definitive way to know about this? What should I type in R as part of '?' or 'help' command?

Comment: I get that. What I am asking is where do I read about the specifications of the behavior when x[FALSE] is executed. As a standalone instruction it seems to behave differently from when used in x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

Comment: The relevant documentation is `help("[")` and the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html). Since you know C/C++ you can also study the source code: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subset.c

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from Roland and G. Grothendieck, I did a quick readup of the R language definition. The answer is right there in $3.4.1

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an
>   empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative
>   indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

Comment: Interesting. Is that behavior documented too. May be I will scan the documentation again.